# How to use onContextItemSelected on contextmenu click android

Tags: java, android, android-activity, onclick, android-contextmenu

I have a `contextmenu` but i want to run some *functions* or *methods* when one clicks on the `items` of `contextmenu`.

I have google out for it and some tutorials show the `onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item)` method but they use `if(item.getTitle() == 'Action1'){}` for the following purpose but i cant use it!

*Because*

- It is not at all standard to use like that!
- `obj.getname()` may differ for some `contextmenu` items which may run
  same `method`

**CODES**

```
  @Override
   public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {  
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);  

    CNList obj = (CNList)v.getTag(); 
    int subs = obj.getsubstance();    

    menu.setHeaderTitle(obj.getname());
     switch(subs){
        case 0:
             menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Invite");  
             menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Call " + obj.getname());
        break;
        case 1: 
              menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Add");  
              menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Send a Message");
              menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Block " + obj.getname());              
        break;
        case 2: 
              menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Add");
              menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Block " + obj.getname());              
        break;      
        case 3: 
              menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Send a Message");
              menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Block " + obj.getname());              
        break;                          
     }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean like this?

```
public boolean onContextItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    if (item.getGroupId() == UNIQUE_FRAGMENT_GROUP_ID) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
        case MENU_OPTION_1: doSomething(); break;  
        case MENU_OPTION_2: doSomethingElse(); break;
    }
}
```